# Manejando campos (multiples selecciones) con valores que dependen de un valor en un campo previo - Django

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-smart-selects

Yo quiero realizar un formulario en donde los valores de un campo en especial dependen de un valor seleccionado en un campo previo.
La idea es que ambos campos deben ser de múltiple selección.

Estuve tranajando con [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), pero tuve estos dos inconvenientes [aquí descritos](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/issues/122):

Investigando en algunos issues y en la web, [hay alguien que tiene el mismo problema que yo.](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/issues/112)

Y en algunos grupos de la comunidad, los usuaruios han dicho que probablemente la aplicación django-smart-selects no soporte algunas funcionalidades e incluso recomiendan hacer lo de las validaciones o chequeo del contenido de los campos via JS o manualmente.

Queria saber si han tenido experiencias con esta inquietud que tengo y si de pronto como la resolvieron.

Conocen alguna aplicación de terceros en la cual los valores de un campo en especial dependen de un valor seleccionado en un campo previo.
La idea es que ambos campos puedan tener valores de múltiple selección.

Cualquier orientación estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo nunca he usado Django pero parece un reto en cualquier Framework o Libreria. En mi experiencia, siempre que quieres hacer cosas muy complejas con un formulario lo mejor es manipularlo con Javascript. Puedes usar solo Jquery o combinarlo con tu framework de preferencia para manejar los eventos.

Te muestro un ejemplo de un **select** cuando cambia de valor usando el evento .change() de Jquery.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Usare la clase `sr-only` de Bootstrap que al aplicarlo a un elemento, le quitara la visibilidad( `visibility: hidden`).

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Supongamos que tienes un select con tres valores y dos campos que dependen de el. Si el valor es **ValorDelSelect1**, entonces muestras **campoQueDepende1** y te aseguras que **campoQueDepende2** este oculto. Si el valor es **ValorDelSelect1** entonces haces lo contrario. Si el tercer valor del Select es uno arbitrario entonces quitas de la vista los dos campos dependientes. El mismo concepto aplica para Radios o grupos de Checkboxes.

```
$('#IDdelSelect').change(function(){
       if( $(this).val() == 'ValorDelSelect1'){
           $('#campoQueDepende1').removeClass('sr-only');
           $('#campoQueDepende2').addClass('sr-only');
       }else if( $(this).val() == 'ValorDelSelect2'){
           $('#campoQueDepende1').removeClass('sr-only');
           $('#campoQueDepende2').addClass('sr-only');
       }else{
           $('#campoQueDepende1').addClass('sr-only');
           $('#campoQueDepende2').addClass('sr-only');
       }
```

});

Si usas una libreria de Javascript como Backbone puedes usar algo muy similar haciendo uso de Views y Events cuando cambie el valor del Input. Esto si haras personalizado para cada Formulario ya que solo con Jquery tu scripts de JS pueden volverse dificiles de mantener.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Diego pues es una de las opciones que he pensado.  En caso de tener que halar de la parte del frontend, ya sería pensar en  cosas como JS o apoyarme en frameworks como angular backbone y cia. De hecho el hacer esto me ayuda a cosas como optimizar mi proyecto django y atacar cosas de velocidad concurrencia (a nivel de presentación) cuando se requiera. Tendré que apropiar esto.  El ejemplo que me referencias .... ¿lo puedo hacer con cosas como backbone?

Comment: Si no haras algo muy complejo, puedes usar solo Jquery, ya que el boilerplate(todo el codigo para solo correr) un framework no vale la pena para tareas pequeñas. Backbone es una libreria que te ayuda a organizar tu codigo, Angular es mas un framework. Ambos han sido usados para crear aplicaciones muy grandes. No recomendaria Angular por que terminaras escribiendo mas "Angular que JS". Backbone  puedes combinarlo con MarionetteJS. Antes de sumergirte con alguna libreria o framework te recomiendo aprender JS muy bien (Closures, Prototypes, Objects, Design Patterns).

Comment: Precisamente no he querido explorar  frameworks o librerías Js debido a que debo apropiar primero muchas cosas de JS puro. Debo mirar como ataco de manera rápida este problemita.